# Can i make tree graph where button means leaf?

Tags: button, graph, tree, elementor

id like to do something like tree graph with buttons. Idk how to explain my idea so ive created image. I build my website via Elementor. Is it even possible please?
[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDgCn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one section using buttons and dividers, set width for the divider, and set it using margin and padding